Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout during install zephyr
When trying to install zephyr, I got an error during installing west with
pip install west

I have no clue how to fix this error
 error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['CSC', 'IME', 'INF', 'OCR', 'PLA', 'SKB', 'Sun', 'UUS', 'Vss', 'Web', 'Boot', 'Help', 'Logs', 'TAPI', 'Temp', 'WaaS', 'debug', 'Fonts', 'Media', 'Setup', 'Tasks', 'addins', 'Speech', 'System', 'WinSxS', 'CbsTemp', 'Cursors', 'dot3svc', 'Panther', 'schemas', 'tracing', 'wlansvc', 'apppatch', 'assembly', 'bcastdvr', 'Branding', 'Firmware', 'IMECache', 'Minidump', 'Prefetch', 'rescache', 'SchCache', 'security', 'System32', 'SysWOW64', 'twain_32', 'WUModels', 'appcompat', 'DiagTrack', 'InboxApps', 'Installer', 'L2Schemas', 'Migration', 'ModemLogs', 'Resources', 'servicing', 'TextInput', 'Containers', 'SystemApps', 'SystemTemp', 'BrowserCore', 'diagnostics', 'IdentityCRL', 'InputMethod', 'Performance', 'PrintDialog', 'AppReadiness', 'Provisioning', 'Registration', 'ServiceState', 'DigitalLocker', 'Globalization', 'RemotePackages', 'Speech_OneCore', 'SensorFramework', 'ServiceProfiles', 'ShellComponents', 'SystemResources', 'ShellExperiences', 'LiveKernelReports', 'PolicyDefinitions', 'LanguageOverlayCache', 'SoftwareDistribution', 'GameBarPresenceWriter', 'ImmersiveControlPanel', 'BitLockerDiscoveryVolumeContents'].


Is this all the error?

Yes that was the full error, my PC did a couple of updates and today i was able to install west via PIP
